# Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...)

Tags: r, postgresql

```
insert = "INSERT INTO filials VALUES (1,'Северо-Западное','Severo-Zapadnoe','SZ');"
dbExecute(connection, insert)
```

Does not work

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: ()
  RS-DBI driver: (t=100)
  RS-DBI driver: (`і&)
...
```

While wothout cyrillic does

```
insert = "INSERT INTO filials VALUES (1,'','Severo-Zapadnoe','SZ');"
```

Comment: Sounds like a possible encoding problem. Have you tried setting `encoding = "Latin2"` in your connection object to the database?

Comment: There are two connection object, this argument is not suitable for both:
driver = dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
connection = dbConnect(driver, host = '55.152.205.52', user = 'postgres', 
                       password = 'pass', dbname = 'dbase')

Comment: Typically I put it in `dbConnect()`, and then it gets passed on to the driver. I haven't used the PostgreSQL driver before though.

Comment: insert1 = paste0('INSERT INTO water_bodies (region,code,wb_name) VALUES (',regnum,',',wbcode,',\'',wbname,'\');')

  insert2 = paste0('INSERT INTO water_bodies (region,code,wb_name) VALUES (6,9880,\'р. Тапса\');')
  insert1 == insert2
TRUE
  dbExecute(connection, insert1) --- ok!
dbExecute(connection, insert2) --- Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :   RS-DBI driver: ()